# TI-84 Multiple Menu Program

Tags: menu, ti-basic

So when you make a menu using the Menu() function, It goes:

Title
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Etc...

But almost every menu already on the calculator has multiple titles that you can choose from, then each with their own options. How would you program that in?

End product being:

**Main** Secondary Tertiary
1. Option 1
2. Option 2
3. Option 3
Etc...

Also, how could I make it so it has more than seven items? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is written in TI assembly, which is completely different from TI BASIC. Maybe one of the new TI programming languages such as Axe might be able to do it. Im not sure since I didnt have the new programming languages when I programmed for calculators

Comment: Okay, so programs that came with it are in assembly, and the others are in basic? Is it possible to mix it a bit? I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty. I also have a mac and a transfer cable.

Comment: i think it is possible to mix assembly with basic, but its annoying and i never got it to work. and i dont recall ti calculators coming with basic programs. this question would be better answered on http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/home

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is several years old but my solution for this fully in TI-BASIC is to have something set up like this (example is from my dice roller program built for D&D)

```
Lbl 00
ClrHome
Menu("How many sides?","Coin",2,"Four",4,"Six",6,"Eight",8,"Ten",10,"Page 2",P
    //Page 2 directs to another menu at label P
Lbl P
Menu("How many sides?","Twelve",12,"Twenty",20,"Custom",C,"One hundred (Percentile)",99, Page 1",00,"Quit",XX
```

You'll see how page 2 is just another menu option that goes to a label like all the others. But it acts like another page or a sub-menu. It does this by going to a label that has another `Menu(` command that looks like the first.

To give you another example from the same program let's look at the d20 roller. First you'll notice in the previous code it directs to label 20.

```
Lbl 20
Menu("Advantage or disadvantage?","Neither",21,"Advantage",22,"Double advantage",23,"Triple advantage",24,"Disadvantage",02,"Back to top",00,"Quit",XX
```

Back to top goes to the top menu at label 00